# How do I install 13.04 alongside windows on an Intel Raid 5?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, raid, raid5

Whenever I try to install Ubuntu I run into issues. All the live CD's don't display the Intel raid 5 and show multiple drives.

When I tried the 12.04 alternative, And the Raring Minimal ISO. The raid Does not show the [proper partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14MO8.jpg).

While The proper partitions [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3ivE.jpg).

Is there any way to solve this issue without recreating the raid?

Answer (score 1):

I would seriously counsel against using this so-called 'fake-raid'/'host-raid', i.e. RAID implemented in the regular chipsets on a motherboard. Linux support has always been a bit spotty. Some get it to work, while for others it only leads to pain and suffering.

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 server on a fake-raid system, actually this was because I noticed that the installer seemed to support it, so I wondered if the tide had turned. Soon after, however, I ran into trouble with this setup so I reinstalled on the 'bare' drives and used Linux' own software RAID. The problems were gone and the machine has been fully functional ever since.

The problem with 'fake-raid' (which, by the way is also the search term you want to use when Googling this issue), is that it (kernel-) support is very much dependent on manufacturer support. In general I give Intel lots of credit for their Linux hardware support, but it seems like this area is still in need of some attention. 
Linux' own software-RAID is vendor-independent and consequently well tested. 
Moreover, in terms of performance real hardware RAID is usually superior, so that's what enterprise users use (and because of support contracts etc. it is also much better supported by kernel drivers).